# MySQL gives correct output but Java raise exception

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I want to show following information -

Date Flight | Name Departure Time |  Business Class Availability | Executive Class Availability | Economy Class Availability

Now all the information are in different tables

```
Table sector - sectorID | description | weekday1 | weekday2 | bfare | xfare | efare
Table flights - flightno | deptime | arrtime | aircrafttypeID | sectorID
Table aircraft - aircraftTypeID | description | bseats | xseats | eseats
scheduleID - flightno | flightdate | bcsavailable | xcsavailable | ecsavailable
```

**QUERY** : show those flights which are scheduled for 17-06-2013 from Kolkata to Ahmedabad and class is business.

Part 1- I am trying to get those flight Nos. whose seats are more than 0 and source and destination matches, 
Part 2 - then I will fetch those records from scheduledflights table whose date and flight number matches. 
I am getting correct output when I run this query in MySQL query window but when I execute same query in Java it gives me an error -

> Column Index out of range, 2 > 1.

SQL Version

```
SELECT flightno
FROM flights
WHERE aircrafttypeID
IN (
SELECT aircraftTypeID
FROM aircraft
WHERE aircrafttypeID
IN (
SELECT aircrafttypeID
FROM sector, flights
WHERE source LIKE  'Kolkata'
AND destination LIKE  'Ahmedabad'
AND sector.sectorID = flights.sectorID
)
AND bseats >0)
```

Output of above query is FJA23 and FJA24 2 records which is correct.

Java Version

```
String origin=jComboBox3.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String target=jComboBox4.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String fclass=jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String search = "";
        if(fclass.equals("Business"))
        {
            search="AND bseats>0";
        }
        if(fclass.equals("Executive"))
        {
            search="AND xseats>0";        
        }
        if(fclass.equals("Economy"))
        {
            search="AND eseats>0";
        }
        String sql="SELECT flightno FROM flights WHERE aircrafttypeID IN "
                + "(SELECT aircraft.aircrafttypeID FROM aircraft WHERE aircrafttypeID IN "
                + "(SELECT aircrafttypeID FROM sector,flights WHERE source LIKE '"+ origin 
                + "' AND destination LIKE '" + target + "' AND sector.sectorID=flights.sectorID) " + search+")";

        System.out.println(sql);
```

Comment: 1) Please show the stacktrace of your error. 2) we do not know if the queries are the same, please show the result of `System.out.println(sql)`.

Comment: What is the Exception, and where is it coming from?

Comment: The SQL only returnes a single column. You cannot refer to column two if there is only one column.

Comment: How do you call your DB, and how do you process the `ResultSet`? Show that code as well.

Comment: @home `SELECT flightno FROM flights WHERE aircrafttypeID IN (SELECT aircraft.aircrafttypeID FROM aircraft WHERE aircrafttypeID IN (SELECT aircrafttypeID FROM sector,flights WHERE source LIKE 'Kolkata' AND destination LIKE 'Ahmedabad' AND sector.sectorID=flights.sectorID) AND bseats>0)
Column Index out of range, 2 > 1.`

Comment: @Gaborch `try
        {
           smt=con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
           rs = smt.executeQuery(sql);
           int i = 0;
           while(rs.next())
           {
               String var1=rs.getString(1);
               String var2=rs.getString(2);
               String var3=Integer.toString(rs.getInt(3));
               String var4=Integer.toString(rs.getInt(4));
               String var5=Integer.toString(rs.getInt(5));
               System.out.println(var1+" " + var2+" "+var3+" "+var4+" "+var5);
           }
        }`

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer a small hint from @Home show me the sparkling light. when I saw printstack it shows my this part of code

```
while(rs.next())
           {
               String var1=rs.getString(1);
               //String var2=rs.getString(2);
               //String var3=Integer.toString(rs.getInt(3));
               //String var4=Integer.toString(rs.getInt(4));
               //String var5=Integer.toString(rs.getInt(5));
               //System.out.println(var1+" " + var2+" "+var3+" "+var4+" "+var5);
               System.out.println(var1);
           }
```

is throwing exception because I am trying to get the data from more than 1 which is not available in resultset

Thank you everybody for looking into my issue.
But still I am confused how can I get data from different table. Do I need multiple queries from each column data.

Answer (score 0):

As you are selecting only one column and 
your exception indicates that you are refering to column index >1 (..probably you are doing this  resultSet.getXXX(2).)

Answer (score 0):

Good that you have figured out the error in your code. As far as fetching data from mutiple tables stands I use following type of SQL in my java code.

select a.col1,b.col2,c.col3

from table1 as a,table2 as b, table3 as c

where a.col1='abc' and b.col2 between 1 and 100;

hope it helps.

All the best cheers...!!